# How do I construct this table relationship in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

Sorry, if this a rather basic question but I'm a SQL Server noob in need of help.

I have 2 types of loan providers, `Lender` and `Pingtree`.

Both `Lender` and `Pingtree` can have a relationship with `MatchService`, which would need to be able to store their `ID`.

At the moment I'm struggling to work out how I can create a relationship between them. To demonstrate, I've created a simple visual of what I want to do in the real world (ringed in red) and what I think could be a possible solution in SQL Server. In essence `Lender` and `Pingtree` would have a `ProviderId` and this would be the `ID` also stored in the `Match` table

[image]

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Are Lender and Pingtree similar tables? If so, add a type column>

Comment: if there are possible duplicate id's in your Lender and Pingtree tables, your idea seems to be a good one. I would use the provider table to get a unique id , and add 2 fields to that table : the foreign id (lender id or pingtree id) , and the type (indicating if it's from lender or pingtree table)

Comment: can one `Match` have both a lender and a pingtree ? Your `and/or` in left schema is not clear. I would say it's just an `or` but I may be wrong.

Comment: Not really. They contain some similar data, but each would also contain contain unique data as well

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - yes the matching service can contain any mixture of lenders and pingtrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were designing this table I would use a Provider to Match table, and store the common attributes in the Provider table. For the non-common attributes, I would create them as a name/value pair table that can link back to the provider Id.

edit: added sample of data structure.

MatchService (Key would be MatchId + ProviderId)

```
|MatchId       |ProviderId|
---------------------------
| 1            | 1        |
| 2            | 1        |
| 3            | 2        |
| 4            | 1        |
```

Provider (Key would be ProviderId)

```
|ProviderId    |ProviderType |ProviderName |StartDateTime | EndDateTime  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1             |Lender       |Stark Ind.   |1/1/2013 00:00|1/1/2014 00:00|
|2             |Pingtree     |MoneyBags    |1/1/2013 00:00|1/1/2014 00:00|
```

Name/Value Pair Table (For Unique, Key would be ProviderId + Name)

```
| ProviderId | Name                    | Value        |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | PointOfContact          | Tony Stark   |
| 1          | Contact Phone Number    | 101-202-3456 |
| 2          | Customer Service Number | 402-123-4567 |
```

Comment: could you provide an example in some shape or form